# Magento - Create product programmatically

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I'm creating products by code.

I'm using Fixed Product Tax with attributo (eco_tax)

It turns out that is not being inserted the rate information, which are they (country, state, value) other product information is OK and the product is created normally, but without the fee.

I am using the following code

```
  ->setFpt(array(
        'website_id'=>0,
        'country'=>'BR',
        'state'=>'0',
        'price'=>10.0000,
        
        ));
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

#### Solution

I found the solution

```
->setData("eco_tax", array(
 array(
'website_id' => 0,
'country' => 'BR', 
'state' => '',
'price' => 10.000,
'delete' => ''
)0
));
```